# How to fix upgrade errors on laravel 9 site?

Tags: laravel

I try to upgrade till 10 laravel 9 site, but I got some errors :

```
 composer install
No composer.lock file present. Updating dependencies to latest instead of installing from lock file. See https://getcomposer.org/install for more information.
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Only one of these can be installed: illuminate/contracts[dev-master, v5.0.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev, v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev, v10.0.0, ..., 10.x-dev], laravel/framework[v10.29.0, 10.x-dev]. laravel/framework replaces illuminate/contracts and thus cannot coexist with it.
    - bensampo/laravel-enum[v5.3.0, ..., v5.3.1] require illuminate/contracts ^9 -> satisfiable by illuminate/contracts[v9.0.0-beta.1, ..., 9.x-dev].
    - Root composer.json requires bensampo/laravel-enum ^5.3 -> satisfiable by bensampo/laravel-enum[v5.3.0, v5.3.1].
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/framework ^v10.29.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v10.29.0, 10.x-dev].
```

Actually composer.json does not have any “illuminate/contracts” :

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "adldap2/adldap2-laravel": "^6.1.7",
        "bensampo/laravel-enum": "^5.3",
        "cviebrock/eloquent-sluggable": "^9.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.8.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.7.2",
        "jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.9.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^v10.29.0",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^3.3.1",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.8.2",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^3.16.0",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1.48",
        "mews/purifier": "^3.4.1",
        "mongodb/mongodb": "^1.16.1",
        "opcodesio/log-viewer": "^1.9.1",
        "phpoffice/phpword": "^1.1",
        "psr/simple-cache": "^2.0",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^2.14.2",
        "snipe/banbuilder": "dev-master",
        "spatie/browsershot": "^3.59"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.9.2",
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.13",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23.0",
        "laravel/breeze": "^1.19.2",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.13.3",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.25.0",
        "laravel/telescope": "*",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.6.6",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^6.4.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.6.13",
        "sempro/phpunit-pretty-print": "^1.4",
        "spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.6.4",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Library/helper.php"
        ],

        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
                "laravel/telescope"
            ]
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

How that make it to work ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The latest `bensampo/laravel-enum` is 6.6.4, try upgrading that.